# printf command wildcard interpretation

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex

I am wondering what behaviour the `printf` command follows, when using wildcards. This question was originally asked me by someone else, but I am confused by the behaviour myself and would love an explanation that helps me understand how the `printf` command works.

Given the following directory:

```
$ ls -a  
.a  a.b  ab.c  b  .b  b.a  b.c  c  c.d  d  d.e  e
```

`$ printf [abcd]*[abcd]` will output `a.b`. `$ ls [abcd]*[abcd]` gives

```
a.b:    

ab.c:    

b.a:      

b.c:      

c.d:
```

as output, and `$ echo [abcd]*[abcd]` results in `a.b ab.c b.a b.c c.d`

Why does printf have a different output? Is it related to regex/shell expantion priorities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set -x` to see what the command really is after the shell expands it. It turns out

```
printf [abcd]*[abcd]
```

in your directory is in fact

```
printf a.b ab.c b.a b.c c.d
```

Now `printf` treats `a.b` as FORMAT (see [`man 1 printf`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/printf/)). It doesn't include `%s` nor anything like it, that's why the rest of the arguments doesn't matter and literal `a.b` is printed.

If you want `printf` to behave more like `echo`, you should specify the desired format, e.g.:

```
printf '%s\n' [abcd]*[abcd]
```

will print

> ```
> a.b
> ab.c
> b.a
> b.c
> c.d
> ```

(Note: use `set +x` to revert `set -x` after you're done with the test.)